# Migration from TPT to TPH in EF 6.1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, migration, tph

Because of performance issue I need to migrate my object hierarchy from TPT to TPH structure. Is there the easiest way to migrate data from one structure to another. Object hierarchy contains around 15 classes, and I don't want to write migration scripts manually. Visual tool, or some kind of migration tool with fluent interface would be nice. Thank you.

P.S. Server is sql server 2014.

Comment: you found a solution for this ?